# Webdriver 2.20 and Firefox 11 (Unable to bind to locking port 7054)

Tags: firefox, selenium, webdriver

I have been using WebDriver with Firefox 3.6 and it works fine. I want to upgrade my Firefox and run my test cases. But for some reason I get the error below when I try to create an instance of `FirefoxDriver`.

This is how I do it. I don't use hub.

```
driver= new FirefoxDriver();
```

I even tried using profile.

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Unable to bind to locking port 7054 within 45000 ms
Build info: version: '2.20.0', revision: '16008', time: '2012-02-27 19:03:04'
System info: os.name: 'Windows Vista', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.6.0'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
```

Answer (score 2):

Even though [the changelog](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/trunk/java/CHANGELOG) states otherwise, Selenium 2.20.0 is not yet fully compatible with FF11. You can either downgrade to FF10 (or 9, not sure now :) ), wait for Selenium 2.21.0 to come out, or try to build your own Selenium from trunk there.

Comment: I tried with firefox 10 too. It does not work. It gets stuck at new FirefoxDriver();  and after some time throws exception. Unable to bind to locking port. I am running this on windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

After having tried all of the solution provided here without any success I simply uninstalled firefox completely (including all profiles) and reinstalled it as suggested here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/webdriver/600j__wM0qY

This surely is not a satisfying solution but a working one.

Answer (score 0):

Even when the 2.20 is not yet fully compatible, it works on my machine with Firefox11. I am supposing, that you still have Firefox 11 and 3.6 installed at the same time. Maybe you should give a try to this:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(new File("path/to/firefox11/firefox.exe"));
```

But however, if it does not work, you had probably bad luck on your machine...

Comment: no .. I have only one version installed at a time. still it does not work.

Comment: So more findings. Finally I figured instantiating FirefoxDriver() fails only when I try to do it in a thread. This fails only if I use selenium version higher than 2.6.0. I tried 2.21 too. It fails. If I instantiate it outside the thread it works fine. What should i do to get it to work inside a thread?

Comment: Same here, any luck ?? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14470591/firefox-selenium-driver-fails-to-load-arbitarily

Comment: I have found a work around here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14470591/firefox-selenium-driver-fails-to-load-arbitarily)